# What are the extra characters in the font name of my PDF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, itext

while extracting font name from pdf i will get some junk characters followed by plus sign and then the font name with font style. i want to remove the junk characters.only for few pdf i get that junk characters. example:MMLPEO+RemingtonNoiseless

```
string curFont = renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "junk" characters indicate that the font isn't embedded completely.
You'll find names such as ABC123+RemingtonNoiseless, XYZ456+RemingtonNoiseless, etc...
meaning that there may be different subsets of the same font inside the PDF.

For an explanation have a look at section 9.6.4 *Font Subsets* of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font — the value of the font’s **BaseFont** entry and the font descriptor’s **FontName** entry — shall
>   begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+). The tag shall consist of exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary,
>   but different subsets in the same PDF file shall have different tags.
>
> EXAMPLE EOODIA+Poetica is the name of a subset of Poetica®, a Type 1 font.

In other words: these characters aren't merely "junk".
If you want to remove them, that's a no-brainer, just use the appropriate string manipulation method,
but be aware that removing them throws away information that may be useful in some contexts.

Comment: *meaning that there are different subsets of the same font inside the PDF* — not necessarily, there merely *may* be.

Comment: Well, it also could be called nitpicking... ;)

Answer (score 3):

For an explanation have a look at section 9.6.4 *Font Subsets* of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font — the value of the font’s **BaseFont** entry and the font descriptor’s **FontName** entry — shall begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+). The tag shall consist of exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary, but different subsets in the same PDF file shall have different tags.
>
> EXAMPLE EOODIA+Poetica is the name of a subset of Poetica®, a Type 1 font.

Thus, those characters aren't *junk*, they are a *tag*.

Comment: +1 — I should have quoted ISO-32000-1; I'm currently in Vienna discussing ISO-32000-2 and related standards.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanku so much for the information. Sorry for using "junk"

Comment: @mkl thanku so much for the information. Sorry for using "junk"